# Affordable alternatives to NewRelic?

Tags: php, monitoring

I'm searching for affordable alternatives to [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/) or an open source application which I can install in my own server. I have used NewRelic for two years but it is very expensive. I need to monitor

```
Application Performance 
Most Time Consuming Transactions  
Database Monitoring
```

It will be great if some one can share your experience with alternative.